# How to solve PDE $(xz-y) \frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}} + (yz-x) \frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{y}}=1-z^2$ using characteristic system of equations

Tags: partial-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

The problem I'm struggling with is to solve the PDE,

$$ (xz-y) \frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{x}} + (yz-x) \frac{\partial{z}}{\partial{y}}=1-z^2 $$

with $x$ and $y$ being independent variables.

**What I Tried**

The only way I know to solve this first-order quasilinear PDE is using the  characteristic system of equations:
$$ \frac{\partial{x}}{xz-y} = \frac{\partial{y}}{yz-x} = \frac{\partial{z}}{1-z^2}$$
The two equations don't seem to be easy to solve directly. I considered finding coeffecients $l(x)$, $m(y)$, and $n(z)$ that satisfy $l(xz-y) + m(yz-x) + n(1-z^2)=0$ but I could not succeed.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: If you add the first two expressions either side of the first equality using componendo dividendo you get $$\frac{d(x+y)}{(x+y)(z-1)} = \frac{dz}{1-z^{2}}$$ which you can use to solve for $z$. Then you can substitute that into the first equality to determine the relationship between $x$ and $y$.

Comment: @mattos Wow! It's a brilliant idea that easily solves the problem.

Comment: Just so you know, you can also look at the difference across the first equality instead $$\frac{d(x-y)}{(x-y)(z+1)} = \frac{dz}{1-z^{2}}$$ and use the integral of this one and the one in my previous comment as your characteristic curves, instead of solving for $z$, substituting into the first equality etc. Alternatively, you might want to solve the problem using the Lagrange-Charpit equations, which is an extension of the method of characteristics when the problem is fully nonlinear (as your problem above is).

Comment: @mattos Actually I did it as you said in your second comment. (It became easy once you introduced the idea.)